# jQuery .on() click event catching dynamic 'data-' attribute in list of buttons to pass value to other function?

Tags: jquery, data-binding, return-value, onclicklistener

I have a dynamic table list of around 40 rows each with an edit button containing a date field.
I also have the following click event script trying to attach to each button via a common class which needs to access the value of a data- attribute within the button image code seen further below:

```
$('.showEdt').each(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   $(this).on("click",$this.data('eValz'), function () {
          alert(this);
   });
 });
```

Example of the edit buttons which are dynamically generated:

```
<img src="edit.png" title="edit" class="showEdt" data-evalz="(eyCKeVua/TNF117)" />
```

### Problem:

The script loads ok, when the edit button is clicked the alert displays:
[object HTMLImageElement]  instead of the data-evalz value ??

Please provide suggestions of how I can access the data unique to the button that is clicked?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You're not using the `on` function correctly. Here's one way you can do this: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/23Qmr/1/)

```
$('.showEdt').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.on("click", function () {
        alert($(this).data('evalz'));
    });
});
```

Also, notice you've written `eValz` instead of `evalz` on your code. Data attributes are case-sensitive so be careful with how you write them.

Comment: Thanks for the response @vape. Spotting the case-sensitive made me feel silly :)  Your response was closely in line with what I was after - +1 for that.  Your fiddle carried over my case-sens error, and I added two image buttons with different data to ensure it worked. I Updated your [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/23Qmr/2/) | **Hiral**'s solution runs off 'body' - Would yours be faster to execute in the code if the page has a lot of lines and controls ?

Comment: Glad I could help :) I'm not certain which one would be faster. I doubt there would be much difference between the two approaches. You should do a quick test to compare if performance means that much to you. I doubt you'd feel much difference for 40 rows though.

Comment: After testing the impact on the page processing, your solution was 12ms faster. [**tighter selection on jQuery**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-jquery-beginners-can-test-and-improve-their-code/) as detailed in the link clearly makes a big difference on large pages if each var/function is able to be direct.  The above benefit was just on your little snippet !  Excellent.

Comment: The 40 rows were what the jQuery '.showEdt' is acting on, but the html page render size has over 1,000 lines. This is where the difference comes in I think.

Comment: This works perfect for dataTables table.reload.ajax() in the on draw event! Kudos!

Comment: Folks, please don't do this.  See https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ for information on using event delegation, which is faster and also works far better for dynamic data.  Hiral's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 11):

```
$("body").on("click",".showEdt",function(){
    alert($(this).attr("data-evalz"));
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/qAm95/)

Comment: Thanks Hiral for the fast response. +1 for that alone.
I tried nearly an identical version of this but made the mistake of putting 'data' where the .attr is.
**One question though -** does having the code bubble down from the body tag make this slower on a 1200 line code page than identifying directly the class '.showEdt' ?

Comment: You are welcome :) I dont think there would be much difference. I suggest you to try out and compare both approaches.

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested. Following the advice in [this excellent article on improving jQuery for speed](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-jquery-beginners-can-test-and-improve-their-code/) the results were really useful: Hiral solution = direct process time (1.935ms) and full impact to page (71.03ms)  || vape solution = direct process time (1.765ms) and full impact to page (59.33ms)

Answer (score 4):

If you're changing the context of 'this' keyword to something else, you can retrieve the data directly from the 'event' object like so:

```
$('element').on('click', function(event) {
    // 'this' here = externalObject
    this.fnFromExternalObject($(event.currentTarget).data('activate'));
}.bind(externalObject));
```

I hope the example above is clear...

Answer (score 3):

or just from the event

```
event.target.attributes.qelemnumber.value
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data attribute is known, you can do it directly with an attribute selector in jQuery, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', "[data-attribute]", function() {
    // Do your tricks here...
});
```