# Is it possible to have more than one id attributes within a single html button?

Tags: javascript, php, html

For example i have a button in a form

```
<button id="test1 test2" value="test">TEST</button>
```

For some reason, I want the id "test1" used to get the $_POST value from the button using php and the id "test2" used to catch the onclick event from the user using javascript.

Is this possible or just some uncomfortably question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible, no. You could classes, though. Also, `$_POST` uses the `name` attribute.

Comment: Try maintaining single unique `id` . Utilize `className` , or `data-*` attributes for one of `test1` or `test2`

Comment: You can't. [http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp). To store aditional data in tag, refer here: [http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp). Hope this helps.

Comment: @StuartWagner - Thanks for the correction for the name attribute to get the S_POST data.

Comment: @guest271314 - Thanks for the information, I've search it and found this one http://jsfiddle.net/23Qmr/1/
I'm working on it now.

Comment: @ConradSiahaan Changed "V" to lowercase within `alert()` http://jsfiddle.net/23Qmr/82/

Comment: @guest271314 - Yeah, actually I'm taking it from this question-post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028100/jquery-on-click-event-catching-dynamic-data-attribute-in-list-of-buttons-t
They told me already.

Comment: @hungndv - It's not really give an answers, but thanks partner.

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple classes and one Id per html page,

A id is meant to identify (distinguish) between elements versus a class combines multiple elements with the same Class

and names don't have to be unique across forms *or* within forms.
The most common use of repeating them is radios:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="my_radio" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name="my_radio" value="2">
    <input type="radio" name="my_radio" value="3">
</form>
```